# Is there a way to write embed code to get my Google Classroom Stream into a widget on ClassroomScreen.com?

Tags: google-classroom

Is there a way to write embed code to get my Google Classroom Stream into a widget on ClassroomScreen.com?
That's pretty much the question. ClassroomScreen.com has an embed widget, but I haven't a clue if or how to write the embed code. Anyone out there done this or something like it already?

I tried searching, but I haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: This question is a bit broad, but from reading https://help.classroomscreen.com/article/27-embed, it looks like the embed just points to a website (no code "in the widget"). You can use the Classroom API https://developers.google.com/classroom to read your stream items. So a rough idea would be for you to create a website that fetches and displays your stream items with the Classroom API, and then you'll link that website in the embed widget. A relatively accessible option for creating a website like this might be using Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web